# Ball page loader animation

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I was wondering if anyone knew how to make an object in this case my ball div appears like it is coming at the screen. Something that is sort of a 3D effect if that makes sense. My code is attached to the bottom.

```js
var ballMotion = gsap.timeline();

ballMotion
.to(".circle", {duration: 3, transform: 'scale(14)'})
```

```css
body {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.circle {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 100px 100px, #FE0, #FAFAD2);
}
```

```html
<figure class="circle"></figure>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.4.2/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using gsap.js, I am unsure exactly how this is working but in pure css you can use transform-style: preserve-3d; and the use perspective() and translateZ() and the @keyframes. I am sure with knowledge of Green Sock you can getting this working. see code below:

```css
CSS

    .wrapper--outer {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 1px;
    }

    .snowman {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      position: absolute;
      top: 18vh;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
    }

    .snowball {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background-color: blue;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10%;
      left: 50%;
      perspective: 550px;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      animation-name: snowball;
      animation-duration: 2s;
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      animation-delay: 2s;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-direction: normal;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    @keyframes snowball {
      0% {
        transform: perspective(550px) translateZ(200px);
      }
      100% {
        transform: perspective(1000px) translateZ(999px);
      }  
    }
```

```html
 
<body>
    <div class="wrapper--outer">
      <div class="snowman">
        <div class="snowball"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JSBin
https://jsbin.com/ropomoquxu/edit?html,css,output